# How to add custom header and footer for wordpress theme

Tags: php, wordpress, wordpress-theming, custom-wordpress-pages

In my project, I'm using WordPress for blog pages and I just wanted to change the appearance of the header and footer of WordPress theme and I don't want to use any plugin for creating header and footer,
 can anyone tell me where I can edit the header and footer code.

Answer (score 0):

It's easy. You can edit the `footer.php` and `header.php` on the theme folder with the HTML/PHP code that you want.

Note: The theme folder is in `/wp-content/themes/{theme_name}` folder.

Comment: You should recommend creating a child theme for making edits to the header and footer of a theme. Otherwise, any edits that the OP does will be lost when the theme is updated.

Comment: Well, maybe it's a custom template or is a template that will never be updated. I created a lot of WP themes that never will be updated because are custom themes or client don't will pay more updates because is a closed project. Anyway, the OP only ask for edit the header and footer not for a Wordpress theme tutorial, but you are in time to reply with a more complete answer :)

Answer (score 0):

/wp-content/themes/YOUR__THEME/header.php , footer.php

Comment: depending what you want.

Comment: Try to read about functions.php in the same folder with header.php and footer.php

Comment: You should recommend creating a child theme for making edits to the header and footer of a theme.  Otherwise, any edits that the OP does will be lost when the theme is updated.